# How to call a certain "function" in a webapp with Node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, coffeescript, xmlhttprequest

So I'm trying to learn Node.js and learn its capabilities. So to see how far it could go, I'm trying to make a bot that can automatically accept trades when they show up in this cute little webapp "https://kittencards.clay.juegos" (Written in CoffeeScript). Currently I'm just trying to make the bot accept a trade. I've already tried looking through the webpack files of the trade menus, and it seems the client emits 'completeTrade' when you accept a trade. So I see two options. Either find a way to find the Accept button and click it, or find a way to simulate emitting 'completeTrade'? I've also been told that looking into XMLHttpRequest would help. **Hopefully** this makes sense. Keep in mind I'm still progressively learning Node.js so if anything I say is wrong feel free to correct me.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I can elaborate more if needed.

NOTE: I don't want someone to write the script for me, that's not what I'm asking. Just maybe links or example code that can help me learn the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you'd rather retrieve id or properties of the trade. Then, passing these data to the method (function) invoked previously by the app when Accept button was clicked.
Anyway a kind of EAI message oriented I daresay.
This way, it would enable your bot to work even if app front changed